# How to compare current year with an integer field in Rules?

Tags: rules, datetime

I would like to compare the current year with an integer field (let's say a "year of subscription" field) using Rules (if the field value is lower than the current year, the user has no access to a specific action on the website).

I have tried many different things, data comparison, text comparison, PHP custom etc. but I did not manage to create this "apparently" simple condition.

I guess I am missing something (a date/time comparison somewhere? the right PHP code to extract the year of the current date? echo date('YY')? strtotime? mktime?).

Could anyone help me?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the rule as follows:

1. Event

   Your event
2. Conditions:

   a. Entity has field

   -> Data Selector = node

   -> Field Value = your date field (mine is field_bp_year)

   b. Execute custom PHP code

   -> Value =

   `return intval([node:field-bp-year]) < intval(date("Y"));`

   where you add the replacement pattern for your date field (mine was field-bp-year)
3. Actions:

   Your action

NOTE: I treated my year as four digits. If you only want 2 digits then use `date("y")`.

Comment: It works for me, thanks for the quick answer. Last thing : if I need Y-1, what would be the PHP syntax?

Comment: I always hesitate to use PHP in rules conditions, mostly because I wonder if it has any type of potential securty issues. Any idea about that?